# Rails don't show validation error messages on associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have simple but frustrating problem with showing validation errors for comments of posts. Error partial shows errors for posts but despite validation works on comments, errors don't render.

comment form partial is inserted into post view:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

errors partial

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
<h2>Errors:</h2>
<ul>
  <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>  
</ul>
```

models:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, :content, :presence => true
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true

end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  validates :body,      presence: true
  validates :commenter, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }

end
```

I have been looking for answer for some time but can't get it working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the `Post` model

`validates_associated :comments`